# Как присоединить таблицу, создаваемую процедурой?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Существует некая таблица, которую создаёт процедура ааа с входными параметрами [@a](/users/106/andreycha),[@b](/users/91/boh),[@c](/users/35/count31),
мне необходимо присоединить эту таблицу с помощью join к другой таблице в процедуре bbb.
Пробовал по-разному, к сожалению, правильный синтаксис мне неизвестен.

Comment: На openwoset он конкретно пишет, что админ запретил его использование, а на openquery совершенно другое. Странно. Очень не хочется переписывать в функцию. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прилинковываете сервер к самому себе и выбираете через OPENQUERY, как таблицу. Это самый простой способ, который я нашел. Есть еще несколько других )

```
sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'LOCALSERVER',  @srvproduct = '',
                   @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc = @@servername

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC sp_who')
```

Правда, OPENQUERY, если мне не изменяет память, для версии MS SQL 2008 является depreciated - т.е., есть шанс, что в следующих версиях поддерживаться уже не будет. Поэтому, более правильным вариантом будет такой:

```
 select * 
   from openrowset('SQLOLEDB',
                   'Server=WIN2003;Trusted_Connection=Yes;',
                   'EXEC sp_who')
```

Вот в этом запросе нужно будет поменять строку подключения - вместо WIN2003 прописать имя своего собственного сервера. Плюс такого запроса еще и в том, что прилинковывать заранее ничего не надо.

Comment: Вроде залинковал, но когда в openquery имя сервера пишу (а имя это ip его), ms sql ошибку выдаёт синтаксиса

Comment: В OPENQUERY вы указываете имя линка - в данном случае - та строка, которая в поле @Server в процедуре sp_addlinkedserver.
Т.е. менять в скрипте вам ничего не надо, кроме текста запроса к хранимой процедуре - вместо 'EXEC sp_who' напишите свой вызов хранимой процедуры.

Comment: Сделал, вот что выдаёт:
Msg 65535, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 

возможно проблема в provider, т.к. на моём серве SQLLNCLI
к тому же, стоит пароль

кстати, если пишу

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([ip сервера], 'EXEC myproc 1, 2, 3')

то ту же ошибку выдаёт

Comment: openrowset не разрешён админом)
версия 2008 R2

Comment: Посмотрите раздел связанных серверов у себя на сервере - должен появиться LOCALSERVER - к нему вы и делаете запрос. Если не появился - возможно, нет прав на создание прилинкованных серверов. первая процедура - sp_addlinkedserver - успешно выполнилась?

Comment: выполнилась успешно, он там есть, правда в строке provider SQLNCLI
смотрю через
select *
from sys.servers

Comment: Если OpenRowSET не разрешен, то тогда и OPENQUERY, вполне возможно, не сработает. Нужно искать другой путь. Например, через функцию - пишите функцию, которая принимает параметры, аналогичные тому, что есть для процедуры, и возвращает таблицу.

Comment: Возможно, проблема с поиском прилинкованного сервера. Попробуйте вместо @@SERVERNAME в вызове процедуры sp_addlinkedserver напрямую указать IP-адрес своего SQL-сервера. Только сначала созданный ранее LOCALSERVER из прилинкованных удалите )

Answer (score 1):

Есть более простой способ.

1. Создаете временную таблицу с соответствующими стоблцами

   Create table #tmp(...)
2. insert into #tmp exec <процедура>
3. Далее джойните вашу таблицу с #tmp